# Angular custom Validator throwing TS errors

Tags: javascript, angular

I wrote a custom password validator, and it's throwing some TS errors.

Validator:

```
import { AbstractControl } from '@angular/forms';

export function ValidatePassword(control: AbstractControl): boolean {
    // Capital letter
    if (!/[A-Z]/g.test(control.value)) {
        return false;
    }
    // Lower Case letter
    if (!/[a-z]/g.test(control.value)) {
        return false;
    }
    // Number
    if (!/[0-9]/g.test(control.value)) {
        return false
    }
    // Length
    if (control.value.length < 8) {
        return false;
    }
    // Special Chars
    if (control.value) {
        return /(?=.*?[#?!@$%^&*-])/g.test(control.value);
    }

    return true;
}
```

I'm getting TS errors that indicate the return values don't line up.

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 5, '(value: string | FormControlState<string>, opts: FormControlOptions & { nonNullable: true; }): FormControl<string>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '(((control: AbstractControl<any, any>) => ValidationErrors | null) | ((control: AbstractControl<any, any>) => boolean))[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'FormControlOptions & { nonNullable: true; }'.
      Property 'nonNullable' is missing in type '(((control: AbstractControl<any, any>) => ValidationErrors | null) | ((control: AbstractControl<any, any>) => boolean))[]' but required in type '{ nonNullable: true; }'.
  Overload 2 of 5, '(value: string | FormControlState<string>, opts: FormControlOptions & { initialValueIsDefault: true; }): FormControl<string>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '(((control: AbstractControl<any, any>) => ValidationErrors | null) | ((control: AbstractControl<any, any>) => boolean))[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'FormControlOptions & { initialValueIsDefault: true; }'.
```

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: A custom validator should be return **null** if no errors. If not pass the test, should be return true or an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with the return type of your function. It should be `ValidationErrors | null` rather than `boolean`. And we need to return `{ nonNullable: true; }` in case of errors. Here I used `invalidPassword`.

Try using -

```
export class AppComponent {
  myForm = new UntypedFormGroup({
    password: new UntypedFormControl(null, (() => validatePassword)()),
  });
}

export const validatePassword = (control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null => {
  // Capital letter
  if (!/[A-Z]/g.test(control.value)) {
    return { invalidPassword: true };
  }
  // Lower Case letter
  if (!/[a-z]/g.test(control.value)) {
    return { invalidPassword: true };
  }
  // Number
  if (!/[0-9]/g.test(control.value)) {
    return { invalidPassword: true };
  }
  // Length
  if (control.value.length < 8) {
    return { invalidPassword: true };
  }
  // Special Chars
  if (control.value) {
    return /(?=.*?[#?!@$%^&*-])/g.test(control.value)
      ? { invalidPassword: true }
      : null;
  }

  return null;
};
```